# Question about android programming using SQL lite

Tags: android, sqlite

i`m still new to android programming, i usually code using Android Studio, here is my question about SQL lite

1. how do you accsess your database from your android phone?
2. where do you put your .db file ? some says i need to put it inside the assests folder
3. i often come through some tutorial where they put database name, create table, drop table query inside the sqllitehelper, why do they
   put it again?
4. after you create the database in DB browser for sqlite software what did you do?
5. this is a question about android programming, i often come through some tutorial about `crud` or something related to database but i
   dont see any `INSERT INTO` QUERY
6. do you need xampp for local server or what?

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/create-a-database-android-application-in-android-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do you accsess your database from your android phone?

If using the Android SDK, you'd typically have a Database Helper (subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper, if the database is a pre-existing database then [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) will copy the database file from the assets folder).

- Note the above assumes the intended use of **SQLite as an embedded database, if you want to share a database across multiple devices then SQLite would probably not be the database of choice (Firebase may be suitable)**.
  .

> where do you put your .db file ? some says i need to put it inside the
>   assests folder

As above, if it's a pre-existing database then the assets folder (in the case of SQLiteAssetHelper) will copy the database to the normally used /data/data//databases/ folder.

- The asset file is compressed and read only so the App would copy the file to a usable folder, typically as above.
- P.S. the file doesn't have to have any file extenstion or could have any valid file extenstion. Nothing that the file name MUST be the same as the database name, as that is the file that will be opened.
  .

> i often come through some tutorial where they put database name,
>   create table, drop table query inside the sqllitehelper, why do they
>   put it again?

This would typically be seen in the **onUpgrade** method.

What happens with the SQLiteOpenHelper subclass is that if the database doesn't exist, then the database is created and is from your perspective empty.

- actually for android at least two system tables will exist;

  - 1) **sqlite_master** which is a table of the tables and other items aka the schema, and
  - **android_metadata** which contains the **locale**

After the database is created the **onCreate** method is called and typically the tables (and possible other items, indexes, triggers, views) will be created using appropriate SQL generally invoked by using the SQLiteDatabase **execSQL** method.

- The database is NOT created just by instantiating the helper an attempt (implied or explicit) has to be made to open the database, it is then that the database is checked for it's existence and created.

As such adding, for example, another table is NOT simply a case of adding more the **onCreate** method, as it will not run.

As such the SQLiteOpenHelper includes a means, by the way of the 4th parameter, the version number to facilitate upgrading the database (e.g. adding the new table).

The version number is stored in the database header and is checked by SQLiteOpenHelper against the value passed. If the value passed is greater than the stored value then **onUpgrade** is called.

- if the value is less then onDownGrade is called and there which will result in an exception should the onDownGrade method not be coded in the sub-class of SQLiteOpenHelper.

Often, onUpgrade will DROP (delete) the tables and then call onCreate to create them and that is what you have seen (probably).

- **Note** ANY EXISTING DATA WILL BE LOST
- to not lose data you would use more complicated/in-depth code.
  .

> after you create the database in DB browser for sqlite software what
>   did you do?

Copy the file into the assets/database folder (if using SQLiteAssetHelper) or sometimes just into the assets folder.

- You may have to create the assets folder and therefore also the database folder.
- I would personally recommend closing DB Browser, opening it again, checking the data is as expected and then closing it again before copying the file.

> this is a question about android programming, i often come through
>   some tutorial about crud or something related to database but i dont
>   see any INSERT INTO QUERY

The android SDK has many convenience methods, that build the SQL on you behalf, including (if the parameters are used accordingly) escaping arguments as required and protecting against SQL injection. Use of the convenience methods is recommended.

Here's an example of what you could instead see (to INSERT) :-

```
public long addUserReg(long studentId, String course) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COL_USERREG_STUDENT_ID,studentId);
    cv.put(COL_USERREG_COURSE,course);
    return mDB.insert(TBL_USERREG,null,cv);
}
```

1. The method is passed two values.
2. A ContentValues object is instantiated (consider this as a list of tuples with a key (name which correlates to the respective COLUMN name) and the value to be placed into that column).
3. A COLUMN value pair is added to the **cv** (an instance of a ContentValues object) COL_USERREG_STUDENT_ID holds the column name.
4. Another value pair is added to cv.
5. note you can consider cv as intelligent e.g. if you pass a byte array then the respective code for adding a BLOB is generated.
6. The **insert** convenience method is invoked, assuming **COL_USERREG_STUDENT_ID** resolves to **studentid** and **COL_USERREG_COURSE** resolves to **course** and **TBL_USERREG** resolves to **course_table** then the resultant SQL would effectively be **`INSERT OR IGNORE INTO course_table (studentid,course) VALUES('1','3')`** *(assuming the studentid value passed was 1 and the course value was 3)*.

> do you need xampp for local server or what?

**No** (I beleieve XAMPP is for **A**pache (server) **M**YSQL not SQLITE **P**HP along with **P**HPMYADMIN) but see above about **SQLite being intended as an embedded database not a client/server type database**. See [Appropriate Uses For SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html)